# How can I get values/options set with $mysqli->options()?

Tags: php, mysqli

With `$mysqli -> options()` we can set some options:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php

but, how I can GET/PRINT the values of some config as:

MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT or MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE?

with

```
print_r(get_object_vars($mysqli));
```

we only get

```
Array
(
    [affected_rows] => 
    [client_info] => 
    [client_version] => 
    [connect_errno] => 
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => 
    [field_count] => 
    [host_info] => 
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 
    [server_info] => 
    [server_version] => 
    [sqlstate] => 
    [protocol_version] => 
    [thread_id] => 
    [warning_count] => 
)
```

but my target is GET the current value of MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE and others parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

MySQL API has the function called [`mysql_get_option()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-get-option.html) but this functions is not exposed through mysqli API.